# How to use scrollToIndex in nativesript radlistview

Tags: javascript, nativescript

i'm having an issue with my nativescript app

I'm trying to sceoll to the bottom of my listview when a button is clicked, but im getting the error cannot read property scrollToIndex of undefined. i know that means getViewById doesnt locate the listview ID

this is my code (view-model.js)

```
const topmost = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame").topmost;
scrollToBottom: function (args) {
        var mScroller = topmost().getViewById("myScroller");
        //mScroller.LoadOnDemandMode = "Manual";
        mScroller.scrollToIndex(this.dataItems.length);
      },
```

is there another way i'm supposed to access the ListView ID

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it

```
const view = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view");
scrollToBottom: function (args) {
        var button = args.object;
        var parent = button.parent;
        let mScroller = view.getViewById(parent, "myScroller");
        //var mScroller = topmost().getViewById("myScroller");
        //mScroller.LoadOnDemandMode = "Manual";
        mScroller.scrollToIndex(10);
      },
```